# Magento EE1.14 Order View not showing order details PHP 7.4

Tags: magento-1.9

I just updated my PHP version from 5.6 to 7.4. I didn't apply a security patch for Magento because most of the core code has been customized to work for our websites. I have made changes in all the files mentioned by the patch though. Now the problem I am facing is that whenever I click on an order it opens an empty page. Does not display any errors on system or exception log even after Magento backend debugging was enabled. Any help would be appreciated.thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can below code add in root index.php file and after check

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ERROR);
register_shutdown_function("fatal_handler");
function fatal_handler() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    echo("<pre>");
    print_r($error);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! this showed me `Declaration of Enterprise_Rma_Model_Rma_Source_Abstract::getAllOptions($withLabels = true) must be compatible with Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Table::getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false) ` error which I fixed using this change https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5237